# PHP: fopen: No such file or directory

Tags: php, fopen

I am trying to create write a log file for my web site. To do this I use the following code to try and open the file. Now the file does not exist yet, but the documentation states that adding "a+" flag ensures that the file is created if it does not exist.

```
 $file = fopen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/logs/mylogfile.txt", "a+");
```

The above code gives me the following error...

```
Warning: fopen(E:/wamp/www/logs/mylogfile.txt) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

What am I doing wrong ? Please excuse me if this is stupid question, I am very new to PHP.

Comment: Do you have write permissions to that folder?

Comment: did you checked your E:/wamp/www/logs/ folder for any file named "tagMetroLog.txt" ?

Comment: Thanks for the response.. how can I check that ?

Comment: yes.. the folder named logs doesn't event exists.

Comment: Create a folder inside your www folder named logs and create the file "tagMetroLog.txt"  or you can use $file = @fopen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/logs/mylogfile.txt", "a+");  It will not show any error

Comment: Ok i will do that.. but isn't what I have done identical to your second suggestion ? or is the "@" symbol before fopen the difference ?

Comment: if you add @ before any of the php function it will not display any warning occured by that function ..

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but because you're under Windows environment, the slash should be backlash no ? Like that `E:\wamp\www\logs\tagMetroLog.txt`

Comment: because \ is escaping, u may want: `E:\\wamp\\www\\logs\\tagMetroLog.txt`

Comment: @MiqdadAli No i don't want the warning to be suppressed. But thanks for the previous suggestion it worked.

Comment: @yvan No that is not an issue. Forward slash works.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

fopen's 2nd parameter "a+" can only create the file if the directory exists. Make sure the logs directory is there. If it's not the case use:

```
mkdir($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/logs/", 0755, true);
```

(true is the key)  before fopen()

Comment: Is it true for writing (`w`) too? Do i need to create the folder before creating the file?

Comment: @fudo yes, it's also for creating a new file with "w"